# How to uncheck all the check boxes after submitting?

Tags: java, checkbox

In my program I am creating a menu where you can select different dishes. The problem is that if they unselect something it is still getting added to the total and after submitting their choices I have to rerun the program in order to pick new choices. How do I make is so when they uncheck it, it isn't still getting added and refreshing the menu after submitting?

This is my listener that deals with when check boxes are selected and the other is for calculating the total.

```
 private class SelectionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (edamame.isSelected()) {
            total1 = total1 + 4.99;
        } else if (calamari.isSelected()) {
            total1 = total1 + 8.99;
        } else if (shrimpTempura.isSelected()) {
            total1 = total1 + 8.99;
        } else if (tempuraCombo.isSelected()) {
            total1 = total1 + 9.99;
        } else if (gyoza.isSelected()) {
            total1 = total1 + 3.99;
        } else if (pepsi.isSelected()) {
            total2 = total2 + 2.99;
        } else if (sprite.isSelected()) {
            total2 = total2 + 2.99;
        } else if (mtDew.isSelected()) {
            total2 = total2 + 2.99;
        } else if (drPepper.isSelected()) {
            total2 = total2 + 2.99;
        } else if (budlight.isSelected()) {
            total2 = total2 + 4.99;
        } else if (budweiser.isSelected()) {
            total2 = total2 + 4.99;
        } else if (playboy.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 12.99;
        } else if (california.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 3.99;
        } else if (volcano.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 13.99;
        } else if (goldenCali.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 7.99;
        } else if (shrimpTemp.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 6.99;
        } else if (tunaR.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 5.99;
        } else if (avocadoR.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 4.99;
        } else if (spicyCaliR.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 5.99;
        } else if (salmonR.isSelected()) {
            total3 = total3 + 5.99;
        } else if (crab.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (salmon.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (tuna.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (whiteT.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (eel.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (crabstick.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (lobster.isSelected()) {
            total4 = total4 + 3.99;
        } else if (bulgogi.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 18.99;
        } else if (kimchiJi.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 12.99;
        } else if (kalbee.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 24.99;
        } else if (soonTofu.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 11.99;
        } else if (bimbimap.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 10.99;
        } else if (dolSot.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 12.99;
        } else if (dukMan.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 13.99;
        } else if (nakJi.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 16.99;
        } else if (tempuraU.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 12.99;
        } else if (nabeyaki.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 13.99;
        } else if (kalbeeTang.isSelected()) {
            total5 = total5 + 14.99;
        }
    }
}


 private class TotalListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        NumberFormat desiredlook = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        desiredlook.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        desiredlook.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        name = getName.getText();
        total = (total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5) * 1.065;
        labelTotal.setText(name + " your total is "
                + desiredlook.format(total));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SelectionListener` would indicate that a single listener is being used for every `JCheckBox`. This creates a problem of the click action from each checkbox being cross dependent and is difficult to manage.

To avoid this cross dependency, you could create individual `ActionListeners` per component.
The [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) interface can be used to create multiple concrete action whereby the amounted to be added can be passed into the constructor of its implementation. For example

```
class SelectionListener extends AbstractAction { 

    private final double amount;
    public SelectionListener(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox)event.getSource();
        if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
            total1 += amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this java code:

```
YourCheckBox.setSelected (boolean isSelected);
```